# findViewById() returns null - what should I do?

Tags: android, findviewbyid, bottom-sheet

I am using a bottomSheetBehavior in my android project. See codes below:

onlineGame.java:

```
 // get the bottom sheet view
        ConstraintLayout llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.end_of_online_game_bottom_sheet_behavior_cl);

// init the bottom sheet behavior
        end_of_online_game_popup = BottomSheetBehavior.from(llBottomSheet);
```

avtivity_online_game.xml:

```
.
.
.

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.androidsample.BottomSheetActivity">

        <!-- include bottom sheet -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/includeBottomSheetBehavior"
            layout="@layout/test_end_of_online_game_popup" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
.
.
.
```

test_end_of_online_game_popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/end_of_online_game_bottom_sheet_behavior_cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    .
    .
    .
```

The problem is this line:

```
ConstraintLayout llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.end_of_online_game_bottom_sheet_behavior_cl);
```

is returning null. I even changed the code place to onResume, but it did not work. When I get another element in `test_end_of_online_game_popup`, it works well and not null.

What is the problem?

tnx

Comment: where is `ConstraintLayout` in xml?

Comment: the root of `test_end_of_online_game_popup` is ConstraintLayout @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Please see [this](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices:

1. `ConstraintLayout llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id. includeBottomSheetBehavior);`
2. `<include layout="@layout/test_end_of_online_game_popup" />`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using included layouts :

Use the find view on the id you have given to the include tag

```
findViewById(R.id.includeBottomSheetBehavior)
```

Or you can omit the id in the layout tag so that its not overridden.

In the < include > tag, only the layout attribute is required. This attribute, is a reference to the layout file you wish to include. This tag also lets you override a few attributes of the included layout.

The above example shows that you can use android:id to specify the id of the root view of the included layout; **it will also override the id of the included layout if one is defined**. Similarly, you can override all the layout parameters.

Source : http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.includeBottomSheetBehavior);//firstly get the root view ID
ConstraintLayout llBottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.end_of_online_game_bottom_sheet_behavior_cl);
```